# Синхронность и асинхронность JS?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такая функция:

```
function hideItemNotification(th) {
 st = true;

 if (th.attr('data-type') && th.attr('data-type') == 'record') {
    st = false;
    // тут вызывается другая функция
    st = true;
 }

 if(st == true){
  // Продолжить работу
 }
}
```

Смысл в том, чтобы если существует th.attr('data-type'), выполнить функцию внутри, и когда она выполнится (вернет true), тогда продолжить выполнение основной функции далее (Продолжить работу).

Я пытался поиграться с флагами, но что-то не то...

Comment: не вижу пока асинхронности. Что происходит в "другой ф-ии"? Пока похоже, что и без флагов всё должно происходить ок.

Comment: > Смысл в том, чтобы если существует th.attr('data-type') выполнить функцию внутри, и когда она выполнится(вернет true), тогда продолжить выполнение основной функции далее(Продолжить работу).

Это стандартный синхронный вызов.